# Knapsack with non-linear constraints & step function including item dependencies

Tags: constraints, knapsack-problem, nonlinear-optimization, approximation

I am trying to solve an optimization which looks similar to a knapsack-problem. The setting is the following:

I am having a pool of ~80,000 players of which I want to build the cheapest squad of exactly 11 players. Each player has multiple attributes, the main position he is playing in, nation, club, league and rating.
The players not only need to be selected but also assigned to a position in the formation:

[image]

Stating the following problem:

> [image: formula]
>
> [image: formula]
>
> [image: formula]

The first constraint is a minimum rating of the squad, which can simply be formulated as a linear constraint. The second and third constraint make sure that exactly one player is selected for each position and each player can only be selected once.
There are several other linear constrains that can occur like a minimum amount of players from one nation or at most three players from a specific club etc.

The chemistry of a squad is a non-linear constraint with a step function.
A players individual chemistry is the product of his position & link bonus.
The position bonus is defined by what the players main position is and where in the formation he is placed in. A central defender placed in the according position gets 3 points, used as a striker he gets 0 points. The bonuses can be seen in the next table.

[image]

This part of the constraint still can be formulated linearly. The link bonus is the non linear component. Each position/node in the formation/graph has a weight between [0-3], two adjacent players have a weight of 1 if they are from the same nation, league or club. Sharing two attributes is a weight of 2 and for three respectively. The bonus for a specific position is the average of all edges multiplied by a factor 3.

> [image: formula]
>
> [image: formula]

This bonus is plugged into a step function, which can be seen in the next figure (mapping values between [0-1] to 0.9 etc.). The link bonus is multiplied by the position bonus and capped to 10. The team chemistry is defined as the sum of the individual player chemistries.

[image: Link bonus step function]

I implemented it as described with miniZinc solving it with the osicbc solver, but even for a player pool of ~100 players this is not really feasible to compute, depending on the additional constraints.
Now I am looking for an implementation that can approximate the solution. I was thinking about a simulated annealing or genetic algorithm. However, due to this chemistry constraint these approaches produce a lot of invalid solutions, wandering around in the dark.

Does anyone have an approach that might be applicable to my problem?

Comment: This looks strange: `sum c(i,j)*x(i,j)` while `c(i,j)=x(i,j)*...` (we are multiplying by `x(i,j)` twice). Of course `x(i,j)^2=x(i,j)` in this case, but anyhow this does not look right. Btw: I suspect Minizinc is already linearizing this when passing the model to CBC.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, yes you are right, I corrected the formula for the constraint.